# How to make percentage labels for bar graphs in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to make a label for a side-by-side bar chart. The label would display the percentage corresponding to that bar. For example, if a bar represents concert ticket sales and accounts for 22% of sales in general, then the bar should display 22%. There is already an option for displaying the total number corresponding to the bar, but not a percentage.

I would use a calculated column for this as per the example [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.3/doc/html/esc/esc_percent_of_total.htm), but I'm connected to external data, so I cannot use the OVER function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the calculated column called percent

```
Sum([sales]) Over Intersect([var1], [var2], ... ) / Sum([sales])
```

Then add a bar graph with the x axis having the same variables that appear above in the `Intersect` function. Make the y axis `Avg([percent])`. Make sure the formatting of `[percent]` is a percentage. Then just add the labels as you normally would.

Comment: OP may not be able to use this expression (specifically the `OVER` keyword) because he's using in-DB instead of in-memory data, but normally this is exactly the way to go!

Comment: I see now that the linked example is a better solution than my own. I have never had the need to connect directly to a database. Perhaps the solution is to make a local copy of the external data and use that instead for the analysis.

Comment: yeah it’s less than ideal working this way (since you lose access to many of Spotfire’s features) but the idea is that you prepare the data in your views at the db level instead. that said, I don’t have a better answer :/

Comment: The issue I run into is that I need the visualization to run on Spotfire Web Player, and to be refreshed in real-time. So I can't use anything other than external data for the analysis.

Comment: Is it possible to add a new table that's a copy of the one you're working with? I'd try myself, but I don't have that kind of setup, unfortunately.